# EF entites via WCF problem

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

I've created a WCF service based on an Entity Framework model.  When I consume the service from a console app, a WinForm app, and a WPF app, everything just works.  I can see the entites and can add/delete/etc.  However, when I try to consume the same WCF service from a web app, I get errors stating that the entities are not recognized.  Looks like the edm is not being included in the service refernce in this case.  Suggestions?  Thx.

Comment: Can you add the exact exception and message? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Think I stumbled on the answer.  I was naming the service reference in my web app the same as my edm, which doesn't seem to bother the console app, WinForm app, and a WPF app, but does cause the problem with the web app.  Curious.  Any insights?